# What message is this "No object for moniker"?

Tags: c#, uwp

When I select desktop as location to save my file in 'FolderPicker' dialog, it says "No object for Moniker". What error message is this? why does it not allow me to select the desktop location? However, there is another shortcut for desktop (under This PC) right below that, it goes smoothly if I select that one. Confusing stuff. Is this the intended behaviour? Please clarify.

```
    FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker() { 
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop 
    };

    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    StorageFolder ToSaveFolder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (ToSaveFolder == null) { return; }
```

[image]

It does not accept the 1st Desktop location. It accepts the second desktop location. Note: 1st one is not a link! neither under the Quick-Access shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the design of `FolderPicker`.

It allow you to get a desktop folder, but when we use the desktop as a suggested start location, `FolderPicker` doesn't pick any folder, and it doesn't treat your startup location as a folder because of some startup locations (like `Computer`) is not a folder.

You can't select the start location as a folder without selecting any folders. But if you select the desktop folder under the Computer directory, this means that a folder has been selected, and it can get the desktop folder normally.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't expect the folder picker to select the suggested location automatically. What I asked is, when I select the desktop as shown in the attached image, it does not accept it. It says "No object for Moniker".  However, there is another shortcut for desktop (under This PC) right below that, it goes smoothly if I select that one.

Comment: Hello, I checked your screenshot, but this is not a normal folder hierarchy, and Desktop should not exist as the parent of Computer. There may be an error in your computer folder path. Have you modified the configuration of your computer?

Comment: No. Never! Even I don't know how to do it. This is the default structure from the beginning itself. However, I check other pcs of my colleagues...

Comment: Hello, I am sorry that you have encountered this problem, but this is not a problem with `FolderPicker`. This happens from a hierarchical sorting error inside the system, and `FolderPicker` just shows it. Because of this, you can't modify this performance through code in UWP application. You can consider backing up your data and then resetting the system.

Comment: Imho this is a really stupid behaviour/user experience. The error message doesn't help and there shouldn't be an error message in the first place. Selecting the "Desktop" from the %userprofile% (i.e. with the full path, e.g. C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop), it works.